# Apply class to button which execCommand on contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

Is there a built in way of keeping a button active when it execute a execCommand on a content editable div ?

example :

```
<input type="button" onclick="doRichEditCommand('bold');" value="B"/>

function doRichEditCommand(command){
    document.execCommand(command, null, false);
}
```

I'd like my button to remain active when the carret is within something where `document.execCommand(command, null, false);` has been applied. I suppose it's doable by checking the parent elements but if there is a built in way it would be better.

In other words I'd like my bold button to be orange when the carret is somewhere which should be bold.

Answer (score 2):

It's doable, but it's really annoying.

Every time the contenteditable changes you call `document.queryCommandState()` to find the state of the text where the caret is, and then update the button class to match. So something like:

```
let div = document.getElementById("myContentEditable");
div.oninput = () => {
  if (document.queryCommandState('bold')) {
    console.log("bold!");
  } else {
    console.log("not bold.");
  }
  return false;
};
```

From there you can apply or remove a style from your bold button to indicate whether the cursor's in a bold section or not. Repeat for the other styles.

The annoying part is that you need to update the button state on several different events. This seems fairly exhaustive to me:

```
div.oninput = div.onselect = div.onchange = div.onkeyup = eventhandler;
```

...but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editorDoc;
    function InitEditable () {
        var editor = document.getElementById ("editor");
        editorDoc = editor.contentWindow.document;          
        var editorBody = editorDoc.body;

            // turn off spellcheck
        if ('spellcheck' in editorBody) {    // Firefox
            editorBody.spellcheck = false;
        }

        if ('contentEditable' in editorBody) {
                // allow contentEditable
            editorBody.contentEditable = true;
        }
        else {  // Firefox earlier than version 3
            if ('designMode' in editorDoc) {
                    // turn on designMode
                editorDoc.designMode = "on";                
            }
        }
    }

    function ToggleBold () {
        editorDoc.execCommand ('bold', false, null);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="InitEditable ();">
    First, write and select some text in the editor.
    <br />
    <iframe id="editor" src="editable.htm"></iframe>
    <br /><br />
    You can toggle the bold/normal state of the selected text with this button:
    <br />
    <button onclick="ToggleBold ();">Bold</button>
</body>
```

editable.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Editable content example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Some text in the editor.
    </body>
</html>
```

some possible solution here: [execCommand method examples](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php)

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my question, I want my Bold button to turn orange when active

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help me but this is not what I'm asking. If you use word or gmail for example the bold button is gonna be active (orange) when the carret is placed at a place where the text is bold. I wondered if there was a built in function to link the button to the contentEditable field. I suspect there is none but that was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I achieved:

JS

```
function format(command) {
    document.execCommand(command, false);
    const button = document.getElementById(command);
    button.classList.toggle("button--active");
 }
```

HTML

```
<button id="bold" onclick="format(this.id)">Bold</button>
```

SCSS

```
button {
    //Whatever you want
    &--active {
            //Whatever you want
    }
}
```

However, it works for general writing. If you select text and apply an effect, the button will be kept active.